# Are there any ways (functions) to save the data of SQS when happen an error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

It is assumed that a problem occurs in the process of reading data of SQS and processing is performed again using the data of SQS.

In this case, are there any functions to save the data of SQS ?

As an assumed example:

1. An error occurred during processing with + fargate
2. Saves the data of SQS
3. The operator confirmed the evacuation data and abnormality contents. It is judged that retransmission is possible
4. Perform processing again using saved data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably find that Amazon SQS does this for you automatically.

The general flow is:

- Messages are placed into an Amazon SQS queue
- Workers **retrieve message(s)** from the queue
- Once a message is retrieved from the queue, it stays in the queue but is marked as '**invisible**'
- Once the worker has processed the message, it **deletes the message** from the queue
- However, if the message is not deleted within a specified time period, the message will **automatically reappear** on the queue, ready to be processed by another worker
- If this happens more than a specified number of times, the message can be moved to a **dead letter queue** for further investigation and handling

Thus, if an error occurs during processing of an SQS message, it will automatically appear later to be processed again.

See: [Amazon SQS Visibility Timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html)